# Limit of a sequence of Lebesgue integrals

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $ f\in L^{1}(E) $ and $ \{E_n\}$ be a sequence of measurable subsets of $E$. If $$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} m(E_n) = 0$$

prove that $$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} \int_{E_n} f = 0.$$

I tried to interchange the integration and the limit with a theorem such as DCT, but I failed to find a suitable function. I would appreciate a hint!

Comment: "I tried to interchange the integration and the limit with a theorem such as DCT, but I failed to find a suitable function." You have something backwards here. By definition $\int_E f=\int f\chi_E$, and it's clear that $|f\chi_E|\le g=|f|$, so that part of DCT is no problem. The reason DCT cannot be applied, at least not directly, is that $m(E_n)\to0$ simply does not imply that $f\chi_{E_n}\to0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: To add to the previous comment, an example of $f\chi_{E_n}$ not going to zero a.e. is given by the typewriter sequence.

Comment: Yes, the convergence part of the theorem is not satisfied. However, I assumed that there may be a way to apply somehow the theorem :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Given $\epsilon>0$ there is a simple function $\phi$ with $\int|f-\phi|<\epsilon$. And now since $\phi$ is simple it is  bounded...

Comment: People downvoting should _really_ explain why...

Comment: Uhm, good hint. Perhaps it would help to first divide $E$ into $E^+\cup E^-$, the sets where $f$ is positive and negative respectively?

Comment: @bartgol I don't see why. Since $|\phi|\le c$ we have $|\int_{E_n}\phi|\le cm(E_n)\to0$, hence $\limsup|\int_{E_n}f|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Oh yeah, because you use $|f|\leq |f-\phi| + |\phi|$, right?

Comment: @bartgol Right. Triangle inequality rules.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you for the hint! This lemma appears in the next section of the book I am currently reading, but I hadn't noticed it. Now the problem's solution is straightforward.